# Why marker position object changed latitude and longitude property names

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, properties, position

I'm using Google Maps javascript API in a mobile application.
When I first implemented the gmaps api, the marker position object had two properties:
position.k (latitude) and **position.A** (longitude). After a few months or so the properties changed to
position.k (latitude) and **position.B** (longitude). I'm not dreaming, I'm very very sure it was **position.A** for longitude before. I tested it.

```js
function saveNewGeoLocation() {
 var position=zx.currentMarker.getPosition();
    $.getJSON("/Serv.svc/UpdateGeoLocation?" + $.param({ latitude: position.k, longitude: position.B, someotherparam:"somevalue" }), function (data) {
        //some other code
    });
}
```

[image: chrome console capture]

Is this Google's way of [image: screwing]ing with us?

Comment: maybe the method changed? can you show us some code?

Comment: Hi! I edited the question with a chrome console screenshot, and a piece of code. My concern now is...will it remain like this? Or do i have to find another way to identify which is latitude and which is longitude...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use undocumented properties of the Google Maps API, they can and will change with every release.

Use the documented properties and methods, which for a [google.maps.LatLng object](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng) are:

- lat() | number | Returns the latitude in degrees.
- lng() | number | Returns the longitude in degrees.

```
function saveNewGeoLocation() {
    var position=zx.currentMarker.getPosition();
    $.getJSON("/Serv.svc/UpdateGeoLocation?" + $.param({ latitude: position.lat(), longitude: position.lng(), someotherparam:"somevalue" }), function (data) {
        //some other code
    });
}
```

Comment: How did i manage to miss that.....Thank you! I also use those coordinates in a function which needs to be optimized, so at that time when I coded it, i thought it would be a tiny bit faster by accessing directly the coordinates with .K and .A instead of calling .lat() and .lng(). Memories are starting to come back LOL

Answer (score 1):

From the Google Maps Javascript API: The [class LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng) is first the lat: number and then lng: number.

What you use is also [getPosition()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference) which is the return value is LatLng.

Comment: so i guess this is what i have to use:
position[Object.keys(position)[1]] for longitude and position[Object.keys(position)[0]] for latitude ... Personally i think that's just stupid