# Google Place Autocomplete - geometry bounds properties

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-geocoder, google-places-autocomplete

I cannot find this answer in the Google docs so I am posting my question here.

As per the Google Places Autocomplete response [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding), `bounds` is one of the returned fields.

However, when console logging `bounds` in the browser, the object has strangely named keys such as `Ba`, `Ab`, `Ra` and so on..

Furthermore, I have noticed that these keys change overtime.

For example, the following code *might* fail within a few days. In the initial search for say, New York, `bounds.Ab.g` may contain a number value.

however, after a few days `bounds.Ab.g` might become `bounds.Bb.g` and the original value will be `undefined`.

```
import PlacesAutocomplete, { geocodeByAddress } from 'react-places-autocomplete'

const GooglePlacesSearchBar = () => {

  const handleSelect = async userInput => {
    const result = await geocodeByAddress(userInput)
    const { place_id, geometry, formatted_address } = result[0]
    const { bounds } = geometry

    const swBounds = [bounds.Ab.g, bounds.Ra.g]
    const neBounds = [bounds.Ab.h, bounds.Ra.h]
    ...

  }
```

This is an example of the `bounds` object printed in console.

```
    bounds: _.Wf
      Bb: Vf
        g: 49.19817700000001
        h: 49.3172939
      [[Prototype]]: Object
      Ra: Qf
        g: -123.22474
        h: -123.023068
```

Could anyone point to a doc or explain what these keys stand for and why they keep changing?

Comment: Those are undocumented properties of the [`LatLngBounds`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#LatLngBounds) object.  They should not be used, use the **documented** methods to access the information you need.

Comment: Related question: [Google maps - Weird geometry.location attributes (G, K)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32614504/google-maps-weird-geometry-location-attributes-g-k)

Comment: Related question: [Why marker position object changed latitude and longitude property names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26115677/why-marker-position-object-changed-latitude-and-longitude-property-names)

Comment: Related question: [item.geometry.location.kb & item.geometry.location.jb returning undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18087008/item-geometry-location-kb-item-geometry-location-jb-returning-undefined)

Comment: Related question: [Google maps api: what are xa and pa in get bounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25393961/google-maps-api-what-are-xa-and-pa-in-get-bounds)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

thanks to @geocodezip for the answers in the comments section.

here is the solution

```
      const result = await geocodeByAddress(userInput)
      const { geometry } = result[0]
      const { bounds } = geometry

      const NELat = bounds.getNorthEast().lat()
      const NELng = bounds.getNorthEast().lng()

      const SWLat = bounds.getSouthWest().lat()
      const SWLng = bounds.getSouthWest().lng()
```

Strange decision by Google indeed.